# Run mocha test to check if object is initialized

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I have this code

```
module.exports = async function checkNetwork(context) {
    const client = new NetworkManager(
       subscriptionId,
    );
};


declare class NetworkManager {
    constructor(credentials: msRest.ServiceClientCredentials | TokenCredential, subscriptionId: string, options?: Models.NetworkManagementClientOptions);
}
```

I would like to test if `NetworkManager` has been initialized. This is what I tried:

```
describe('schedule', () => {
        let revert;
        let clientFake;
        beforeEach(() => {
            clientFake = {
                constructor: stub().resolves(),
            };
            revert = reverseProxy.__set__({
                'NetworkManager': stub().returns(clientFake),
            });
        });
        it('run lookup', async () => {
            await stubContext(reverseProxy);
            expect(clientFake.constructor.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
    });
```

But this doesn't work. I am getting `AssertionError: expected false to equal true`.

Can someone advice?

Comment: For one thing that seems like a test of implementation, not of behaviour - what does checkNetwork actually _do_? For another if it news up a NetworkManager it's tightly coupled to that implementation, could you invert the dependency and pass an instance in instead of the subscription ID?

Comment: @jonrsharpe this is a small part of checkNetwork function. It checks if some DNS endpoint is available. Anyway, the point of the test where I am struggling is to check if `NetworkManager` has been created (I have the object initialization, but I do not now how to check that).

Comment: What does `reverseProxy.__set__` do? Does it modify the original object or does it return a new instance of the object? In the latter case, you may need to work with the return value, i.e. `revert`, and use that as arg for `stubContext` call.

Comment: The short answer is I wouldn't assert on that. Without more information about the real implementation it's hard to say how you _should_ test it, but you don't need to have an expectation for every line. Maybe the test double should be a class too, so without instantiating it the methods wouldn't be accessible and the code under test would throw an error.